# Optimising for loop, avoiding wasteful lookups

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
    var postcodes = [['BD1',8],['BD2',20],['BD7',30]];

    var rangeColours = [['red',10],['black',20],['blue',30]];

    var postcodeColours = [];

    for(var i=0; i<postcodes.length; i++) {
        var match = 0;
        for(var x=0; x<rangeColours.length; x++) {
            if(postcodes[i][1] <= rangeColours[x][1] && match == 0){
                postcodeColours.push([postcodes[i][0],rangeColours[x][0]]);
                match = 1;
            } 
        }   
    }
```

The output of the code is: (which is fine by the way)

```
    [BD1,red][BD2,black][BD7,blue]
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to make the code more efficient especially with regard to reducing the wasteful look ups that occur in the second for loop? At the moment I'm using the "match" variable and setting it to 1 if the value of the postcodes array element is less than the value of the rangeColours array element to ensure the push doesn't repeat for each postcodes array element, is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Is that how the `rangeColours` continues... incrementing by 10? If so, you should be able to eliminate the inner loop entirely.

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity No, it can contain any number of values, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really wanted to optimize lookups you could remove the redundant lookup of `postcodes[i]` and `rangeColours[x]` within the loop body by stashing it in a local

```
for(var i=0; i<postcodes.length; i++) {
    var postcodeCurrent = postcodes[i];
    var match = 0;
    for(var x=0; x<rangeColours.length; x++) {
        var rangeColourCurrent = rangeColours[x];
        if(postcodesCurrent[1] <= rangeColoursCurrent[1] && match == 0){
            postcodeColours.push([postcodesCurrent[0],rangeColoursCurrent[0]]);
            match = 1;
        } 
    }   
}
```

I'm unsure if this would have a noticeable performance impact though.  It feels like a micro optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement

```
for(var i=0; i<postcodes.length; i++) {
    for(var x=0; x<rangeColours.length; x++) {
        if(postcodes[i][1] <= rangeColours[x][1]){
            postcodeColours.push([postcodes[i][0],rangeColours[x][0]]);
            break;
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is the very first thing that should be changed in the code.

Comment: Yeah, to me the other stuff seems like micro optimization that might be done by the compiler itself (not sure about that tho). And this code seems far more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<postcodes.length; i++) {
    var match = 0,
        codes = postcodes[i],
        coloursLength = rangeColours.length;
    for(var x=0; x<coloursLength; x++) {
        var colours = rangeColours[x];
        if(codes[1] <= colours[x][1] && match == 0){
            postcodeColours.push(codes[0], colours[0]);
            match = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using your `match` variable or `break`, you could set the value of `x` once you've found your match.

```
for(var i=0; i<postcodes.length; i++) {
    for(var x=0; x < rangeColours.length; x++){
        if(postcodes[i][1] <= rangeColours[x][1]){
            postcodeColours.push([postcodes[i][0],rangeColours[x][0]]);
            x = rangeColours.length;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use that over a break statement?